QtSqlTableModel: rowRemoved signal not emitted
In Qt 6.8.0 I have a SQLite database. I want to be notified when the user removes a row from the model. Here my code:
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("mydb");
QSqlTableModel model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable(mytable);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

connect(_model, &QSqlTableModel::rowsRemoved, this, [=](const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
{
    qDebug() << first << last;
});

when the user clicks on the "Remove" QPushButton I execute this code:
// check validity of the selection, etc...
int row = view->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();
model->removeRow(row);
model->submitAll();

the row is correctly removed, but the signal rowsRemoved is not emitted.
I tried to catch the rowsInserted signal and instead it works fine when I add a new row.
The docs say:

Note: Components connected to this signal use it to adapt to changes in the model's dimensions. It can only be emitted by the QAbstractItemModel implementation, and cannot be explicitly emitted in subclass code.

from what I understand a subclass (like QSqlTableModel) cannot emit directly this signal, but the underlying QAbstractItemModel should emit ifself.
Is my connect statement wrong?

QSqlTableModel is a little bit special as removeRows does: "The model retains a blank row for successfully deleted row until refreshed with select()" + submitAll does: "In OnManualSubmit, on success the model will be repopulated". I hardly use that class but if I understand correctly, no signal is emitted when you do removeRow (because the rowCount() does not change) and submitAll will trigger a modelReset signal.

PS: In my previous comment, I meant that no deletion signal is emitted by removeRow but most likely, a dataChanged signal is. Anyway, you could perhaps use the beforeDelete signal instead, though I would assume the deletion may fail after the signal is emitted. If that possibility or the timing at which the signal is emitted (during submitAll instead of removeRow) are not acceptable, you need to edit your question to make it clear.

@Atmo, thanks for the hints. I've just tried the first one and the dataChanged signal is not emitted.

The beforeDelete is emitted. It is more a workaround than a real solution, but for this specific case I can live with it! Anyway, it's not clear to me why they decided to not emit removeRow when the row is actually removed.

@Mark Because the rows aren't actually removed from the model, the model is actually reset due to the call to submitAll(), which causes beginResetModel() and endResetModel(). The model is repopulated (as the docs also explain), and this is necessary because there is no absolute way of knowing if the pending changes were only about a row removal, and SQL doesn't even have a concept of "which row was removed" (or added), nor it retains any "row index" of what has changed.

Fine if you can use the beforeDelete signal, although you will have the same limitations as your other recent question, that is, you cannot test if the query is successfully executed in a slot connected to that signal. The alternative is for you to put e.g. a QSortFilterProxyModel between your QSqlTableModel and your view, and have it filter the blank rows out, with the rowsRemoved signal emitted in the process.
